# Testing current value of cycle

Tags: twig

I want to render blocks of HTML in alternate orientations. Is this the correct syntax in order to get the current value of cycle?

```
{% if ( {{ cycle(['odd', 'even']) }} == 'odd' ) %}
foo
{% elseif %}
bar
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `cycle(['odd', 'even'])` should not be inside `{{ }}` in the `if`
   statement
2. `cycle()` should have a second parameter given that counts the amount of loops
3. the `{% elseif %}` should either have a condition or be changed to `{% else %}`

This is what you should do to get the code to work as you want it to (loop 10 times):

```
{% for i in 0..9 %}
    {% if cycle(['odd', 'even'], i) == 'odd' %}
        foo
    {% else %}
        bar
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want the for to loop objects you can use `loop.index` (starts at 1) instead of `i`:

```
{% for object in objects %}
    {% if cycle(['even', 'odd'], loop.index) == 'odd' %}
        foo
    {% else %}
        bar
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

or `loop.index0` (starts at 0):

```
{% for object in objects %}
    {% if cycle(['odd', 'even'], loop.index0) == 'odd' %}
        foo
    {% else %}
        bar
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```